# update-grub2 could not find custom kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel, 19.10

I've compiled a new kernel based on 5.4.18-xanmod10 kernel. Then I've installed it:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*5.4.18-xanmod10-custom*.deb
```

But after installing, it have not been found by `update-grub2`:

```
root@lenovo:~# ls /boot/
config-5.3.0-29-lowlatency           memtest86+.elf
config-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom        memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-5.5.0-3.2-liquorix-amd64      System.map-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
config-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64      System.map-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
config-5.5.4-xanmod3                 System.map-5.5.0-3.2-liquorix-amd64
grub                                 System.map-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
initrd.img                           System.map-5.5.4-xanmod3
initrd.img-5.3.0-29-lowlatency       vmlinuz
initrd.img-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom    vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
initrd.img-5.5.0-3.2-liquorix-amd64  vmlinuz-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
initrd.img-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64  vmlinuz-5.5.0-3.2-liquorix-amd64
initrd.img-5.5.4-xanmod3             vmlinuz-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
initrd.img.old                       vmlinuz-5.5.4-xanmod3
memtest86+.bin                       vmlinuz.old

root@lenovo:~# update-grub2
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

There're other kernels present, but after reboot only `lowlatency` kernel and memtest are present in the grub menu. Also, during update it shows the same kernel two times. Previously, before generic cernels moving to another folder, generic and lowlatency kernels have been listed during grub update.

How could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following three commands also solve this problem, by turning off the executable bit on 09_lowlatency and turning on the bit for 10_linux, in accordance with the text in /etc/grub.d/README.lowlatency.  I recommend editing /etc/default/grub to change GRUB_TIMEOUT to a positive value, prior to invoking update-grub as well.

```
# chmod -x /etc/grub.d/09_lowlatency
# chmod +x /etc/grub.d/10_linux
# update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, but the solution is not very nice.

1. Copy lowlatency grub configuration file into new custom grub config file: `sudo cp /etc/grub.d/09_lowlatency /etc/grub.d/08_custom`
   I got `09_lowlatency` file by following [instructions](https://adamstechblog.com/2017/08/21/deploying-a-low-latency-kernel-with-ubuntu-server-16-04-lts/):

   > First, let’s visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/. This step is a little
   >   less obvious. The package “ubuntustudio-default-settings” contains a
   >   file named “09_lowlatency”. This file is a GRUB configuration file we
   >   can use to assure our lowlatency kernel is booted first and assures it
   >   will stay that way.
2. Take away these files so they will not duplicate grub menu entries and will not be duplicated in a list during `sudo update-grub2` command execution:
   `sudo mv /etc/grub.d/10_linux /home/myuser/backup/ && sudo mv /etc/grub.d/09_lowlatency /home/myuser/backup/`
3. I changed one `case` statement in the `08_custom` file:
   Before changing it was:

   ```
   case "x$machine" in
       xi?86 | xx86_64)
           list=
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*lowlatency /vmlinuz-*lowlatency /boot/kernel-*lowlatency ; do
               if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done
           list2=
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*generic /vmlinuz-*generic /boot/kernel-*generic ; do
               if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list2="$list2 $i" ; fi
           done ;;
       *)
           list=
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*lowlatency /boot/vmlinux-*lowlatency /vmlinuz-*lowlatency /vmlinux-*lowlatency /boot/kernel-*lowlatency ; do
                     if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done
           list2=
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*generic /boot/vmlinux-*generic /vmlinuz-*generic /vmlinux-*generic /boot/kernel-*generic ; do
                     if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list2="$list2 $i" ; fi
           done ;;
   esac
   ```

   After changing it became:

   ```
   case "x$machine" in
       xi?86 | xx86_64)
           list=
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*lowlatency ; do
               if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*generic ; do
               if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*xanmod10-custom ; do
               if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done ;;
       *)
           list=
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*lowlatency ; do
                     if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*generic ; do
                     if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list="$list $i" ; fi
           done
           for i in /boot/vmlinuz-*xanmod10-custom ; do
                     if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" ; then list2="$list2 $i" ; fi
           done ;;
   esac
   ```

My `ls -alh /boot` and `sudo update-grab2` commands show the next:

```
$ ls -alh /boot
total 275M
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4,0K feb 17 00:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4,0K feb 13 09:55 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 231K jan 17 15:59 config-5.3.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 231K jan 17 15:59 config-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 138K feb 16 03:54 config-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 216K feb 15 19:56 config-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 237K feb 15 16:06 config-5.5.4-xanmod3
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K feb 17 00:28 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   35 feb 16 09:06 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  46M feb 13 21:37 initrd.img-5.3.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  46M feb 14 00:01 initrd.img-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  12M feb 16 08:36 initrd.img-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  53M feb 16 09:07 initrd.img-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  52M feb 17 00:32 initrd.img-5.5.4-xanmod3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   30 feb 16 09:06 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 4,5M jan 17 15:59 System.map-5.3.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4,5M jan 17 15:59 System.map-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,2M feb 16 03:54 System.map-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3,9M feb 15 19:56 System.map-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5,1M feb 15 16:06 System.map-5.5.4-xanmod3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 feb 16 09:06 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
-rw-------  1 root root  11M jan 17 16:35 vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11M jan 17 16:35 vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6,6M feb 16 03:54 vmlinuz-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8,9M feb 15 19:56 vmlinuz-5.5.0-4.1-liquorix-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7,2M feb 15 16:06 vmlinuz-5.5.4-xanmod3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 feb 16 09:06 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-lowlatency

$ sudo update-grub2
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.18-xanmod10-custom
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-29-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

I removed excessive code not needed in my case, then copy-pasted a pair of `for` loops for `lowlatency` kernel and changed `lowlatency` to `xanmod10-custom` in it.

```
$ ls -alh /etc/grub.d/
total 136K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4,0K feb 17 00:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 141 root root  12K feb 17 00:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  11K feb 11 16:57 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 6,2K feb 11 16:57 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  16K feb 17 00:28 08_xanmod_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  37K feb 11 16:57 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  13K feb 11 16:57 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2,0K feb 28  2016 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  12K feb 11 16:57 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1,4K feb 11 16:57 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  214 feb 11 16:57 40_custom
```